# Unignore folders under /bin TFS everywhere

Tags: eclipse, tfs

Apparently TFS everywhere by default ignores everything under /bin folder. The problem is that I have the following dir structure

```
config
bin
   project_a
   project_b
```

I need to version all these folders, but TFS everywhere is not automatically tracking changes in my projects under /bin folder. As the entire project is under /Bin the context menu Team > Unignore is disabled.

How can I say to TFS everywhere that I need to track the changes on these files?

Comment: Why do you have stuff that you need to version under bin? That is extremely bad practice.

Comment: not in this case, I'm developing some extensions to SAP hybris. And according to their guidelines all extensions should be under bin.

Comment: The output is under bin. Not code. Output should not be under source control in a bun folder.

Comment: No, the code should be under bin. check this example to get a better understanding about hybris. http://www.hybrishub.com/2014/06/hybris-tutorials-setting-up-accelerator.html

Answer (score 0):

You can go to the Source Control Explorer, find the file in question. If it's there you should be able to unignore it by right clicking and going to properties. If it's not there you should be able to add it like any other file.